# Non-Final Action response timeframe?

Tags: non-final

What is the deadline time frame for a Non-Final Restriction Requirement, one month or two months?

Answer (score 1):

Read the restriction requirement.  The answer will be printed right on it!  It used to be a month, but now it's two months.

See: https://www.uspto.gov/patents/init_events/PLT_Memo_to_Examiners_12-13-2013.pdf

Of course, you can extend the time up to six months by paying extension of time fees.